# Observable<any> is not assignable to type Observable<any>

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, observable

I am using angular 5 with ionic 3.
I have one interface:

```
export interface IAny {
    getDataSource: Observable<any>;
}
```

Components which implements this interface has method:

```
getDataSource () {
      return Observable.of(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'] as any)
 };
```

This method should return different types of dataSources, some time it will be simple array of string , some time array of objects, some time the simple object.

Is it possible at all ?

Comment: Does it work if you try: return Observable.of<any>( ...

Comment: `['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']` is not any, but an any-array, therefore: `['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'] as any[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several way of doing this :

```
return Observable.of<any>(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'])
return Observable.of(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']) as any
return Observable.of(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']) as Observable<any> // For code completion
```

All should work. You can just replace `any` with your type.

By the way, your interface should be this

```
export interface IAny {
    getDataSource(): Observable<any>;
}
```

You declare a function, not a variable.

Better, as [@nicowernli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027936/nicowernli) suggested, if you want to type your returns on the fly, declare your interface and your functions with generic types :

```
export interface IAny {
  getDataSource<T>(): Observable<T>;
}

getDataSource<T>() {
  return Observable.of(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'] as any)
};
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? This is a completely valid answer.

Comment: Exactly, this is total valid answer, also I would say that using generics is the best solution you can get

Comment: @nicowernli I would agree, but can you declare an interface with a generic typing ?

Comment: I still get and error in both cases. Maybe that is just VS2015 type script linter, but error is still there. In first example error is the same.
In second example error is: any' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: Yeah that's because your interface should be written like this : `getDataSource(): Observable<any>;`. You're declaring a function, not a variable.

Comment: The 2nd example is not valid, as the whole return value is `any`, not Observable<any>

Comment: @David it is, `Observable<any>` complies with `any`. But I get your point let me edit my answer.

Comment: I just tried and actually all 3 examples lead to typescript error. But I don't get why

Comment: @trichetriche You're right, it works if the interface is declared as `()=>Observable<any>` Maybe you should edit your answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Thanks for the answer. Yes the real problem was my interface implementation.

Comment: No problem, be sure to see the last edit of the post

Comment: Yes, this update with generic is even better. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but you don't need to cast the array to `any`.

If you don't, in your example, your function is of type `() => Observable<string>`, a type compatible with `() => Observable<any>`, which is the type of the method defined in the interface.

I mean, if you have:

```
let a: () => Observable<any>;
let b: () => Observable<string>;
```

Then you can do:

```
a = b;
```

Because `any` is compatible with any type in TypeScript.

Comment: If I remove casting I get Error.   Observable<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'. I even tried to change interface to accept Observable<any[]>', but without success.

Comment: The problem was in my interface, when I fixed it, this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and want to avoid the 'any' type as much as possible (and in this case your any-castings) you could use a Type Alias especially for your value.

It could look something like this:

```
// Just add your desired types that are possible return values
type DataSourceType = Array<string> | Array<object> | object;
```

You find everything about Type Aliases at the [TS Docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

You could even take it one step further and replace the generic object type with your custom type.

Comment: I thought about his implementation but choose 'any', since it is less code :), but you are right it is a better way.